# Data not inserting into MySql remote databse via Phonegap app

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am trying to set up an android app with Jquery & PHP using Ajax to post the data from a form into a database on a remote server. It all works fine in local testing, but when I build the app and try to do it via my tablet it doesn't work at all.

I imagine it's something very simple which i'm doing wrong. Here is the code I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Submit a form via AJAX</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function onSuccess(data, status)
{
data = $.trim(data);
$("#notification").text(data);
}

function onError(data, status)
{
// handle an error
}        

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#submit").click(function(){
var formData = $("#callAjaxForm").serialize();

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "http://xxx.co.uk/cgi-bin/process.php",
cache: false,
data: formData,
success: onSuccess,
error: onError
});

return false;
});
});
</script>

<!-- call ajax page -->
<div data-role="page" id="callAjaxPage">
<div data-role="header">
<h1>Name Form</h1>
</div>

<div data-role="content">
<form id="callAjaxForm">
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="firstName">First Name</label>
<input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" value=""  />
<label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
<input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" value=""  />
<h3 id="notification"></h3>
<button data-theme="b" id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
<div data-role="footer">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see it's very basic - I have found a tutorial and used the code from that for testing.

The php code is:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
include("conn.inc");

$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastName'];

$q1 = "insert into customers (Name,Contact) values ('$firstName','$lastName')";
$r1 = mysqli_query($cxn,$q1) or die ('Error Q1');

?>
```

Again very basic as i'm a newbie - but any help as to why the data submitted doesn't post when done via android would be massively appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check with an alert if your deviceready is fired or not.

use this

```
$(document).on('pageshow', "#callAjaxPage",function () { ...... });
```

instead of this

```
$(document).ready(function() { ...... });
```

Comment: what are the errors you are noticing? Try to put an alert in the `onSucces()` and `onError()` call and see which call is being fired. Also check at your server if you are receiving any request from the tablet. log calls on the server for all request recieved in detail.

Comment: The alerts fire when I run the page locally in a browser - but when I build the app via phonegap and submit the form through my tablet it just re-loads the page of the form and doesn't insert the data. I'm sure it's something simple that I'm missing!

Comment: try using `$("#submit").click(function(e){` inside that, in the first line put `e.preventDefault();` @Ginelli

Comment: Still the same, works via a web browser but not via the app once built by phonegap. I assume this is something which is possible via android?! Or am I just being totally dumb?

Comment: I also keep getting this message in the console log 'XMLHttpRequest for http://xxx.co.uk/cgi-bin/process.php required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).' But I have 'header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");' in my php and '<access origin="*"/>' in config.xml!!